# woocommerce change variation-id to product attribute name

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook, hook-woocommerce

I would like to reconstruct the code by working with the names of the product attributes instead of the id variations.

From this code:

```
function action_woocommerce_thankyou( $order_id ) {
    // Get $order object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    // Get items
    $items = $order->get_items();

    // Set variable
    $found = false;

    // Set variable
    $output = '';

    // Loop
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        // Add whatever variation id you want below here.
        if ( isset( $item[ 'variation_id' ] ) && $item[ 'variation_id' ] == 9647 ) {
            $output = 'Thank you for buy VARIABLE A-9647';
            $found = true;
            break;
        }

        if ( isset( $item[ 'variation_id' ] ) && $item[ 'variation_id' ] == 9648 ) {
            $output = 'Thank you for buy VARIABLE B-9648';
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Get payment method
    $payment_method = $order->get_payment_method();

    // Payment method = basc & found = true
    if ( $payment_method == 'bacs' && $found ) {
        $output .= ' YOUR PAYMENT IS BACS';
    }

    // Print result
    echo $output;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'action_woocommerce_thankyou', 10, 1 );
```

---

I would like to reconstruct the code by working with the names of the product attributes instead of the id variations

How to change this code

**from**

```
variation_id
```

**to**

```
product name attribute
```

more exactly these lines:

```
if ( isset( $item[ 'variation_id' ] ) && $item[ 'variation_id' ] == 9647 )

if ( isset( $item[ 'variation_id' ] ) && $item[ 'variation_id' ] == 9648 )
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean this?

```php
function action_woocommerce_thankyou( $order_id ) {
    // Get $order object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    // Get items
    $items = $order->get_items();

    // Set variable
    $found = false;

    // Set variable
    $output = '';

    // Loop
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        // The WC_Product object
        $product = $item->get_product();

        // Add whatever attribute you want below here.
        if ( !empty( $product->get_attribute( 'pa_kleur' ) ) ) {
            $output = 'Thank you...1';
            $found = true;
            break;
        }

        if ( !empty( $product->get_attribute( 'pa_jaar' ) ) ) {
            $output = 'Thank you...2';
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Get payment method
    $payment_method = $order->get_payment_method();

    // Payment method = basc & found = true
    if ( $payment_method == 'bacs' && $found ) {
        $output .= ' YOUR PAYMENT IS BACS';
    }

    // Print result
    echo $output;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'action_woocommerce_thankyou', 10, 1 );
```